# How to efficiently read specific lines of a CSV?

Tags: python, pandas, keras

I am working on training a Keras neural network model on a training set with ~5,000,000 rows. I'm reading in only a few lines of this file at once for training using code similar to the following:

```
n_lines = 5000000
skiprows = np.delete(np.arange(1, n_lines), np.arange(first_line, first_line+batch_size))

X = pd.read_csv('training.csv', skiprows=skiprows)
```

Some transformations are performed on `X` and it is then passed to the model using `model.train_on_batch(X, y)`.

I think this is currently the bottleneck in my training procedure so I want to know if there is a more efficient way to accomplish this.

I timed it to check the difference (`training_data.csv` has 50,000 lines):

```
pd.read_csv('training_data.csv') # 0.86 seconds

n_batches = 1000
for i in range(n_batches):
    skiprows = np.delete(np.arange(1, 50000), np.arange(i*50, (1+i)*50))
    pd.read_csv('training_data.csv', skiprows=skiprows)
# 152.23 seconds to iterate through all 1000 batches
```

Comment: Can you add more code? what are you doing with X?

Comment: Are you sure this is the bottleneck? Deep learning is an computationally expensive procedure.

Comment: @VikasNS `X` is eventually passed to a Keras `model.train_on_batch` call.

Comment: @ncfirth Training the same model is much quicker when I load an entire subset of the data, say 50,000 lines, into memory. It takes roughly 12 seconds to generate a batch of 10 samples using this method.

Comment: I'm confused, correct me if I'm wrong. Your training on more data, so it is taking more time? If your facing problem with memory, then you should custom generator to load data and use model.fit_on_generator()

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "bottleneck "?

Comment: I mean that my training time (per batch) takes much longer using the method I described above than if I read all of the data into memory. The time to read the data doesn't seem to increase linearly with the number of lines read. It seems to be closer to log time. And I cannot use `fit_generator` because I need to reset the model states at specific times during training.

Comment: Though I don't believe this is an XY problem. I'm simply trying to find the fasted way to read specific lines from a csv.

Comment: Can you time how long it takes to read in the whole file vs how long it takes to read in specific lines? Don't include the neural network training time, just those parts of the code. It's really surprising to me that this takes longer, let alone is the bottle neck.

Comment: I will do so and report back.

Comment: I'm intrigued as to what is going on here, but a quick fix would be to just read in the dataframe with skiprows once and then save it out to another csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found an approach that will work using the `chunksize` argument of `pd.read_csv`.

```
for batch in pd.read_csv('training_data.csv', chunksize=50):
    # transform/reshape batch
    #model.train_on_batch(batch, y)
    next
```

This reads 1,000 batches of size 50 in about 3.86 seconds, and allows me to use the `train_on_batch` method. I still need to find a better way to read the `y` data, but I think I may look into storing both `X` and `y` in a single csv and using `chunksize`.